# How we can retrieve the key of a dropdown field in a PDF Template using smarty in SugarCRM 7.x

Tags: pdf, smarty, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM 7.x PDF Template created using PDF Manager I want to retrieve the key of a drop-down field for checking some conditions. What is the best way to retrieve this key?

Let's consider that I have a dropdown field named 'my_field' which have a custom options list named 'my_options' attached to it.

The options list 'my_options' attached with 'my_field' is defined like this:

```
$app_list_strings['my_options']=array (
  'a' => 'Option Alpha',
  'b' => 'Option Bravo',
  'c' => 'Option Charlie',
);
```

Let's also consider that in my module 'my_field' has a value of 'b' saved in the database and in my pdf template I want to retrieve this value 'b'
so in pdf template, I use

```
{$fields.my_field}
```

and it returns 'Option Bravo'

Is it possible to retrieve its key value i.e. 'b' in some way?

Comment: Possible workaround: create a calculated varchar field that just has the dropdown field as formula. That new field will then contain the key and can be used in the template instead of the dropdown. Note: You will need to recalc/resave existing records if you want to fill the field in those.